# memory management: open vs string-building

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've got over 3 million Tweets that I've scraped from the API. I have some code that processes the tweets, and I want to then serialize them to JSON and write them to a file. Since it's so many things, I've been running into some memory issues. I'm planning on using itertools.imap, but my function options are basically either

```
def string_builder(self, thing):
    self.output_string += json.dumps(thing)+"\n"
...
def parse_writer(self, dest):
    itertools.imap(self.string_builder, *iterator that processes the tweets and returns serializable output*)
    with open(dest) as f:
        f.write(self.output_string)
```

or

```
def write_wrapper(self, thing, dest):
    with open(dest, "a") as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(thing)+"\n")
...
def parse_writer(self, dest):
    itertools.imap(self.write_wrapper, *iterator that processes the tweets and returns serializable output*)
```

(I guess there's also the option of leaving the file object open and then repeatedly writing to it.)

I know building the string and then writing once is normally the right thing to do. I'm wondering if that still holds when the string in question is so big. I'm trying to reduce my memory footprint as much as possible, because I'm taxing my resources basically to the limit as it is.

Comment: Write individual JSON lines to the writer, instead of the whole thing at once.

Comment: "building the string and then writing once" is *not* "normally the right thing to do". Why not? Because it's insane ;-) Write when you have something *to* write, move on to the next, and keep the output file open for the duration (so that file buffering can move the bytes efficiently to disk).

Comment: I had literally no idea--I was taught that strings are "cheaper" than I/O, but I guess Ezequiel's answer, below, makes more sense. Thanks everybody!

Comment: In-memory string processing *is* cheaper (time-wise) but since  there are no inter-dependencies between lines and you're ultimately writing them all to a file, that IO is always going to be the bottleneck. So in this case you can stream it and avoid overwhelming your relatively limited amount of RAM :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, building a file in-memory and writing all at once isn't on any best-practices guides I know :) It basically defeats the purpose of any lower-level buffering and runs into the exact problem you're facing.

The best thing to do is to write line by line, i.e. streaming the writes.

```
with open(dest, "a") as file:
    for tweet in iterator_that_returns_tweets:
        file.write(json.dumps(tweet) + "\n")
```

Comment: So when I tried doing this with all the files at once, it kept locking up, but when I did something like `for fil in list_of_filenames:
e = Extractor([file]); e.write_and_parse()`
it worked just fine. I'm still not sure if it was the parsing or the I/O that was the real problem.